# managed array or array of managed objects in Visual C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, managed

For a practice PacMan

```
array<bool>^ aEtats;             //declared: an array of true/false states

aEtats = gcnew array<bool>(100); //this array will correspond with an array of "Pills"

for each (bool b in aEtats)  
     b=true;
```

I get an array of 100 "false". Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just change the for each loop to use a reference, e.g. for each (bool% b in aEats). – Ben Voigt

Answer (score 1):

The *bool* type is a value type, you get a copy of the value in the for-each statement, not a reference.  So you are setting the copy to true, this doesn't propagate back to the array element.  Use a simple for loop instead:

```
Etats = gcnew array<bool>(100);
for (int ix = 0; ix < Etats->Length; ++ix)
    Etats[ix] = true;
```

Comment: Or just change the `for each` loop to use a reference, e.g. `for each (bool% b in aEats)`.

Comment: ok,thanks works, used the second solution offered since the goal is to familiarize with C++/CLI management. You should see my other question: similar confusion!